# JsonArray return null value

Tags: php, mysql, json

Below is my php code:

```
public function getMainChatList($myPhoneNo){

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT receiverPhoneNo,name FROM users,friend WHERE users.phoneNo=friend.receiverPhoneNo AND senderPhoneNo=? AND chatted = 'y' ORDER BY update_time DESC");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $myPhoneNo);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    $result = array();

    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
         array_push($result,array('receiverPhoneNo'=>$row['receiverPhoneNo'],'name'=>$row['name'],));
     }              
     //echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
     echo json_encode($result);
     echo json_last_error();
     $stmt->close();        
    }
```

And the json return

```
[{"receiverPhoneNo":null,"name":null},{"receiverPhoneNo":null,"name":null}]0
```

json_last_error() returns 0. I have no idea why it return null.
And I execute the sql statement on xampp MySQL server directly.
Below is the result.

[result.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjLlE.jpg)
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried that on Mysql console to see the output that query? Is it possible that those fields are empty?

Comment: Hi jonystorm. I have tired that on the mysql console and it has the result.

Comment: You can click result.jpg above to see the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`bind_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) instead:

```
public function getMainChatList($myPhoneNo)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("
        SELECT receiverPhoneNo, name FROM users, friend 
        WHERE users.phoneNo = friend.receiverPhoneNo 
        AND senderPhoneNo = ? 
        AND chatted = 'y' 
        ORDER BY update_time DESC
    ");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $myPhoneNo);
    $stmt->execute();
    // bind
    $stmt->bind_result($receiverPhoneNo, $name);

    $result = array();

    while($stmt->fetch()){
        $result[] = array(
            'receiverPhoneNo' => $receiverPhoneNo,
            'name' => $name,
        );
    }

    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Comment: @VSCircus sure glad this helped

Answer (score 0):

this should put the associative array from the entire query directly into your `$result` array

`$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`